# Radon-Nikodym derivative of vector-valued measure with respect to another vector-valued measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, integration, optimal-transportation

Let $(X, | \cdot |)$ be a Banach space.

I am interested in whether one can **extend the definition of the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition)**
$$
\text{KL}(\mu \ \Vert \ \nu)
:= \int_{\Omega} \ln\left(\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\text{d}\nu}\right) \; \text{d}\mu
- \mu(\Omega) + \nu(\Omega),
$$
which is defined for measures $\mu$, $\nu$ on $\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Definition) of some set $\Omega$, with
$\mu \ll \nu$ (that is, [$\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures)) so that the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative) $\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\text{d}\nu} \in L^1(\Omega, \mu)$ exists,
**to [$X$-valued measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure#Definitions_and_first_consequences) $\mu, \nu$ of bounded semi-variation**.

One problem clearly is to give meaning to the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative) $\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\text{d}\nu}$ if both measures are vector-valued.

A standard definition (cf. [Diestel, Uhl: Vector measures](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-15), Def. 3 in Chp. 3, p. 61) is:

> **Definition 1 (Radon-Nikodym property).**
> Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a finite measure space, that is, $\mu \colon \Sigma \to [0, \infty)$ be a countably additive measure and $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra over a set $\Omega$ with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$.
> A Banach space $X$ has the *Radon-Nikodym property with respect to $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$* if for each $\mu$-continuous vector measure $G \colon \Sigma \to X$ of bounded variation there exists a $g \in L_1(\mu, X)$ (the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $G$ with respect to $\mu$) such that
> $$
> G(E)
> = \int_{E} g \; \text{d}\mu
> $$
> for all $E \in \Sigma$.
> Lastly, $X$ has the *Radon-Nikodym property* if it has the Radon-Nikodym property for all $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$.

Here, $L_1(\mu, X) := L_1(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu; X)$ is the space of (equivalence classes of) Bochner-integrable functions $\Omega \to X$ and $G$ is $\mu$-continuous if $\lim_{\mu(E) \to 0} G(E) = 0$ (p. 49 and 10 in [Diestel, Uhl](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-15)).

**My question** is:

> What happens if we instead let $\mu \colon \Sigma \to Y$ be a vector-valued measure with values in a Banach space $Y$ such that there exists a bilinear map $X \times Y \to Z$, $(x, y) \mapsto x y$,  where $Z$ is a Banach space such that there exists a constant $K > 0$ with $| x y | \le K | x | | y |$ for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$? Is this extended definition of the Radon-Nikodym property meaningful, e.g. would it still be true that e.g. reflexive spaces have the Radon-Nikodym property?

This bounded-bilinear-form condition is sufficient for the integral $\int_{E} g(s) \; \text{d}\mu(s) \in Z$ to be well-defined for $g \colon \Omega \to X$, $\mu \colon \Sigma \to Y$ and $E \in \Sigma$ (cf. [Bartle: A general bilinear vector integral](https://eudml.org/doc/216873), 1956).

*Note:* There already is a generalisation of the KL divergence to measures taking values in the *cone* of real symmetric positive semidefinite matrices in [Quantum Optimal Transport for Tensor Field Processing by Péyre et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08731.pdf) in section 1.3.